# Taking mysql backup using .bat and taskscheduler failed run viataskscheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I was create a "export.bat" and put these line of code

```
 @ECHO OFF
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=root --host=localhost --password=mind --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --routines --events --no-data "db_ows" > ows_back.sql
```

when direct run its working fine.

But i was trying with Task Scheduler on WIndows Server 2012, its failed.
The action setting of task scheduler are as follows.

[image]

Comment: What is "its failed"? Does it not execute the script, or does it remove `System32` folder?

Comment: direct hit the batch job works,Here failed means "while scheduling a task with task scheduler its not working" where will i put batch file 'export.bat'

Answer (score 3):

I changee the action settings In Task Scheduler Action Tab

[image]

It works.